# Codeigniter Error : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

**I am not able to recognize why this error is coming again and again.** 
Basically I am trying to edit a students' data

I am using the following files :

Controller - students

View - students_edit

Model - codegen_model

My Controller is as follows :

> function edit(){
>           $this->load->library('form_validation');          $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
>
> ```
>     if ($this->form_validation->run('students') == false)
>     {
>          $this->data['custom_error'] = (validation_errors() ? '<div class="form_error">'.validation_errors().'</div>' : false);
>
>     } else
>     {                            
>         $data = array(
>                 'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
>                 'password' => $this->input->post('password'),                     
>                 'phone' => $this->input->post('phone'),
>                 'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
>
>         );
>                   if ($this->codegen_model->edit('students',$data,'id',$this->input->post('id'))== TRUE)          {
>           redirect(base_url().'index.php/students/manage/');          }           else            {
>           $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>An Error Occured</p></div>';
>
>       }       }
>
>   $this->data['result'] = $this->codegen_model->get('students', 'id,username,password,phone,email', 'id = '.$this->uri->segment(3),NULL,NULL,true);
>           $this->load->view('students_edit', $this->data);        
> }
> ```

The view is as follows :

```
<?php     

echo form_open(current_url()); ?>
<?php echo $custom_error; ?>
<?php echo form_hidden('id',$result->id) ?>

        <p>                         
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $result->username ?>"  />
        <?php echo form_error('username','<div>','</div>'); ?>
        </p>


        <p>                         
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $result->password ?>"  />
        <?php echo form_error('password','<div>','</div>'); ?>
        </p>

<p>     <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $result->phone ?>"  />
        <?php echo form_error('phone','<div>','</div>'); ?>
        </p>


        <p>                         
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $result->email ?>"  />
        <?php echo form_error('email','<div>','</div>'); ?>
        </p>       

        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The Codegen_model is as follows :

```
function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
    $this->db->where($where);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result($array) : $query->row() ;
    return $result;
}
```

I am getting the following error when I try to load the view student_edit :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/students_edit.php

Line Number: 5
```

When I had tried `result->id` wid other example it was working  fine but here I am not able to figure out where is the error.

Any solutions will be of great help. Thanks in advance.
NC

Answer :

The code seemed to work fine but the oly problem was in the query and what @Rick said was right.

Comment: yes kind off but the issues were different

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a problem with your database query.  I would use

```
die($this->db->last_query());
```

After the line

```
$query = $this->db->get();
```

And then try running the query to see if there are any errors.

I would also put in some checks in your view to see if $result->id exists before echoing it out to avoid the error

Comment: I tried print_r($result); but its showing an empty array

Comment: Also die($this->db->last_query()); doesn't make any difference and the same error is thrown.

Comment: Your first comment is your answer. If $result is returning an empty array in the model then it's not sending an object to the view. Your query is failing. If you're sending the query data that should return a result you need to troubleshoot why, you also need to handle the possibility of an empty result in the view. Meaning if the user asks for data that doesn't exist the view needs to handle that more elegantly than just failing.

Comment: Oh ok ok.. Got it thanks a lot the problem was here $this->db->limit($perpage,$start); I was passing 0, 0 for both.. $perpage and $start..

Comment: @Rick Calder : thanks a lot. I ll keep those points in mind

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that `codegen_model->get` returns null something that is not an object. Probably `null`?

Try doing a `var_dump($result)` to see exactly what you get from `$this->codegen_model->get('students', 'id,username,password,phone,email', 'id = '.$this->uri->segment(3),NULL,NULL,true);`

Btw that codeine model... that is not how you should use a model in CI.

Comment: var_dump($result) is throwing an empty set : array(0) { }. But the query statements seem to be correct ??? And how should I use codegen_model ??

Comment: I see you fixed your answer. So related to the model, you should have a `students_model` and that should have a methods that handle the interaction with the students table (get_by_id(), add(), update(), etc) Read here more http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: yes but I have a common model so I gave a common name. thanks for the info anyways

Comment: Yes but how is a "common model" any different then calling $this->db form the controller? The whole point of MVC is that the controller doesn't know about what database tables you have.